# pthread_join called by static instance destructor : undefined behaviour?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I'm having issues with my thread management on an embedded system using pthread.

I reduced the code to this sample program :

```
struct test;
struct destructionHelper
{
    ~destructionHelper()
    {
        printf("~destructionHelper()\n");
        if(instance)
        {
            delete instance;
        }
    }
    test* instance;
};

void* foo(void *)
{
    printf("thread sleep for 15seconds\n");
    sleep(15);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

struct test{
    static destructionHelper desHelper;

    test()
    {
        pthread_create(&thread,NULL,foo,NULL);
        desHelper.instance=this;
    }
    ~test()
    {
        printf("joining...\n");
        pthread_join(thread,NULL);
        printf("joined\n");
    }
    pthread_t thread;
};
destructionHelper test::desHelper;
```

And I call this test class like this :

```
int main() {
    new test();
    printf("Sleep for 10 seconds\n");
    sleep(10);
    printf("main ended\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The reason I used this `destructionHelper` is because `test` should be a singleton (and since I don't have C++, no Meyers singleton for me).

The code is working fine on my desktop but not on the embedded platform I'm aiming for. (The kernel of the target is linux 2.6.28.9)
It will wait forever when reaching `pthread_join`. It seems that the thread is closed by the system (not listed anymore with `ps`) before I call `pthread_join`. The man page of `pthread_join` says it should return if the thread exited but I suppose the thread is not valid anymore ?

Is there a way to avoid this while still being able to free my singleton ?

Comment: Why all the complication. Just make your `test` on the stack at the start of main.

Comment: I did say it should be using a singleton pattern...

Comment: Why should test be a singleton? Most of the time that's an anti-pattern. Trying to control the lifetime of threads this way is bizarre. When a much simpler alternative is available, stick with simple.

Comment: The aim was to make a threadpool for the whole program

Comment: You don't need a singleton for that. Create the thread pool in main, and hand over a reference to anything that needs it.

Comment: Is this really the only way? So if I ever write a threadpool class, (singleton or not) that is being used as a static member for any class, it'll blow up? (It would make sense to have the same pool for all the instance of a same class)